# Can I verify that a transaction was signed by the right secret key without sending it to the network? (ALGO)

Tags: algorand

I was wondering if i would be able to verify that the transaction was signed by the right secret key without sending it to the network?

I want to verify that it's the right wallet doing the action, but without actually sending it to the network.

The goal is to have a kind of authentication with the wallet. The user just sign the transaction but it doesn't go to the blockchain, i just want to verify that's him.

Not sure if it's actually possible or not. If not, is there a way to identify a wallet by making him sign something, but not making him pay the transaction price?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! There is an official Algorand library for this kind of verification.

[Source](https://github.com/barnjamin/sdk-extras/blob/master/js/verify.ts)